# How to loop through a Firebase child's children and add their keys to a list?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a Firebase real-time database that has a child, with children underneath it.
I want to loop through the child and add the keys of the children to a list.

This is what I'm doing:

```
public ArrayList<String> debateKeys() {
    debatesChildren.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                tempItems.add(postSnapshot.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return tempItems;
}
```

When I use the debugger, it shows that `tempItems` returns nothing, and `onDataChange` doesn't even execute, which means it doesn't even run the for loop.

How do I go through the child's children and add their keys to a list?

Answer (score 4):

addValueEventListener() is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The listener you passed to it will get invoked some time later when the results are finally known.  This means you're returning an initially empty `templates`.  Whoever is holding on to `templates` might be in for a surprise if and when the contents update at an unpredictable time after your function returns.  Not only that, the contents will continue to change over time as your listener gets called with **each and every change** to the location represented by `debatesChildren`.  This is a really terrible situation.

First of all, if you need to access data only once, you should be using [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) to ensure that your listener gets called only once.

Second, you should not try to make an async call like that into a synchronous call.  Some other part of your code needs the results of a database query, they should be receiving that through a callback, not by a function return value.  You will have to figure out how you would like to do asynchronous programming in you app, and wire it up as you see fit.